# CSS 2 column layout within left column of outer layout

Tags: html, css

Ok I have a site design that uses the standard 2 column layout. In the left column of the OUTER layout I want to place an inner 2 column layout. So basically a two column layout nested within a column of an outer 2 column layout.

Here is an example of my code that is not working.  The example at the top just shows my outer 2 column layout that works fine. Below that is my nested 2 column layout that is broken. What am I doing wrong?

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UJssV/1/)

Here an image of basically what I want to do
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are wanting to achieve, is it possible that you include a picture of what you do want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a `div` with a `clear:both` on it that was causing the right outer to float after the inner divs.  I removed that and added some jQuery to give the outer divs equal height, [as you can see in this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/UJssV/2/)

If you want the outer divs to have equal height without any Javascript then you will probably need to make them table cells.